# Strict inequality changes to weak inequality over limit

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$.

I can't get why from
$$
|f_N(x)-f_n(x)|<\varepsilon
$$
with $N\in\mathbb{N}$ fixed.

On taking the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$
$$
|f_N(x)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon.
$$
Why does the $<$ turn into $\leq$ formally speaking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we have: $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{R}},(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{R}},\subset R$ with  $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x,\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=y$ and $x_k<y_k, \forall k\in \mathbb{N}$ then, for all $\varepsilon>0 \Rightarrow  {\varepsilon \over 2}>0$, exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such: if $n>N$, then

$$ x-{\varepsilon \over 2}<x_n<y_n<y+{\varepsilon \over 2} $$

So $x<y+\varepsilon, \forall \varepsilon>0~~\therefore x\leq y$

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason that any strict inequality can become equality in the limit: for example, if $a_n(x)=(1+x^2)/n$, then for every $n$ and $x$, $a_n(x)>0$, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n(x) = 0 $.

(This is also why it is best to prove integral inequalities in the same way as sum inequalities, rather than just taking limits of sum inequalities: you can lose what cases actually give you equality.)

Comment: I was hoping a answer with $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$, there's no way to get it with this?